# multi threaded python3 server

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, server

Hey guys i'm trying to make a multi threaded chat server...so my server is multi threaded but it only sends back the data to the same client that sent the message. I'm not sure how to go around this. For a chat room i would need it to send to everyone in there.

here is the server

```
import socket
import threading

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 4559


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4559))
s.listen(5)

def accept_send(conn):
    message = b'welcome to hex0server'
    conn.sendall(message)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        conn.sendall(data)



while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=accept_send, args=(conn,)).start()
```

and just a simple client

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4559))

while True:
    recieved = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print("rec: " + recieved)
    inpa = input("Enter message: " )
    inpa_enc = inpa.encode("utf-8")
    s.sendall(inpa_enc)
```

would appriciate some advices on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you just creating empty list somewhere atop your code, then, in `accept_send`, `append()`ing the `conn` to the list. When you then need to send a message to the chat room, just iterate over the list and send it to everyone in the list.